# How can I change enum value inside it scope

Tags: java, enums

This is my enum class

```
public enum Turn{
    BeginUserTurn,UserTurn,
    BeginEnemyTurn,EnemyTurn;

    public void change(){
        if(this==BeginUserTurn)this=BeginEnemyTurn;
        else this=BeginUserTurn;
    }
}
```

and I have Turn valiable

```
Turn turn;
turn=Turn.BeginUserTurn;
```

I want to change turn value from user to enemy's turn by call

```
turn.change()
```

but problem is in enum class,line 6,7 , have an error say

> the left-hand side of an assignment must be variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reassign `this`. It is a keyword, not a variable.
Maybe try something like this:

```
turn = turn.change();
```

and have `change()` return the next `Turn`:

```
public Turn change() {
    if (this==BeginUserTurn) return BeginEnemyTurn;
    else return BeginUserTurn;
}
```